# Variables in bash seq replacement ({1..10})

Tags: bash, seq

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
start=1
end=10
echo {$start..$end}
# Ouput: {1..10}
# Expected: 1 2 3 ... 10 (echo {1..10})
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In bash, brace expansion happens before variable expansion, so this is not directly possible.

Instead, use an arithmetic `for` loop:

```
start=1
end=10
for ((i=start; i<=end; i++))
do
   echo "i: $i"
done
```

#### OUTPUT

```
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4
i: 5
i: 6
i: 7
i: 8
i: 9
i: 10
```

Comment: and should output be 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10?

Comment: it's possible, but it is a little bit ugly because one starts another shell to do the variable expansion before the brace expansion: `start=1;end=10;for i in $(bash -c "echo {$start..$end}");do echo $i;done`

Answer (score 29):

You should consider using `seq(1)`. You can also use eval:

```
eval echo {$start..$end}
```

And here is `seq`

```
seq -s' ' $start $end
```

Comment: I don't have the seq command in my shell

Comment: @Tyilo Now I understand.

Comment: And seq is also deprecated anyway

Comment: @Tylio Is it ?! I didn't know. Why is it deprecated ?

Comment: @cnicutar Here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

Comment: @Tyilo I agree one should favor internal commands / structures over external programs. But what happens if I use something that doesn't support that syntax.. like `dash` maybe ? Or `ash` ? Or `tcsh` ?

Comment: @Tyilo What shell/OS are you in? Solaris? I've never seen seq not present on any Linux distro. In fact, its even in the GNU coreutils: http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/seq-invocation.html

Comment: @opsguy FreeBSD doesn't have it either (although it's in `ports`).

Comment: @opsguy coreutils != POSIX standard. Sure, it's there in Linux, but there's more operating systems in the world.

Comment: For what it is worth, "deprecated" does not mean the same thing as "isn't advisable"

Comment: using `eval` is as horrid here as in most other places, don't get used to it or you'll find yourself leaving command injection vulnerabilities some day

Comment: To make eval safe here, just force the variables into integers with `eval echo {$((start))..$((end))}`

Comment: @phicr, `$((var))` is not safe if the value of `var` has not been sanitized.  See [Security Implications of using unsanitized data in Shell Arithmetic evaluation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172103/264812).

Comment: @pjh you're right, I forgot that index evaluation is part of arithmetic and it allows arbitrary commands. Maybe something like $((${var%%\$*})). Altho of course the proper thing to do is to validate the data as valid integers either by code invariants or explicit conditionals. (in the hypothetical case eval is necessary)

And I don't know where my head was at 1 yr ago that I didn't realize that my "solution" could easily lead to potentially silent hard to find errors anyway, even if it had been a working one, hehe.

Answer (score 10):

You have to use `eval`:

```
eval echo {$start..$end}
```

Comment: That's like using a jackhammer to pound a nail. It's dangerous (literally, introduces potential shell injection vulnerabilities if any of your values come from untrusted inputs), and not the right tool for the job. `for ((i=start; i<end; i++)); do ...; done`.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have `seq`, you might want to stick with a plain for loop

```
for (( i=start; i<=end; i++ )); do printf "%d " $i; done; echo ""
```

Comment: This is the only working non-scary (ie not eval) answer. Did not know bash had c style loops

Answer (score 2):

I normally just do this:

```
echo `seq $start $end`
```

Comment: Look at my comment to cnicutar's answer

Comment: `seq` is a non-standard tool (literally, not specified in POSIX).

Comment: Let alone the fact that `seq` is non-standard, but the echo + command substitution is just a silly combination.

Comment: @ilkkachu not if you need to add a newline.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky, well, the bigger difference is that the unquoted command substitution folds the whitespace to single spaces (unless `IFS` is changed from the default). So you get the numbers all on the same line, not one line each like the default with `seq`. But if you want that, you could just use `seq -w ' ' 1 10`. If you do  quote the command substitution, on the other hand, then `echo "$(seq 1 10)"` and `seq 1 10` have exactly the same output. Command substitution strips trailing newlines (there's one), and `echo` adds one back.

Answer (score 2):

Are you positive it has be BASH? [ZSH](http://www.zsh.org/) handles this the way you want. This won't work in BASH because brace expansion happens before any other expansion type, such as variable expansion. So you will need to use an alternative method.

Any particular reason you need to combine brace and variable expansion? Perhaps a different approach to your problem will obviate the need for this.

Answer (score 1):

use -s
ex:
seq -s ' ' 1 10
output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10