# How to print counter and comma separated field in bash?

Tags: bash

I have limited experience with Shell scripting. I was trying to print the comma-separated field with their index number.

I found a similar question here [Variables in bash seq replacement ({1..10})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191146/variables-in-bash-seq-replacement-1-10) .

```
IN="abc,def,123"

for i in $(echo "$IN"  | tr "," "\n")
do
  echo $i
done
```

How can we also print the counter number?

My attempt:

```
count=1
for i in $(echo "$IN"  | tr "," "\n")
do
  echo $count $i
  count+=1
done
```

But this does not work.

Comment: With bash: `declare -i count=1; count+=1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `let` command to perform arithmetic:

```
let count+=1
```

or an arithmetic expression:

```
((count+=1))
```

BTW, there's no need to use `tr` to split the input on commas, you can set `IFS`.

```
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=, 
for i in $IN
do
    echo $i
done
IFS=$saveIFS
```